# HTTP to HTTPS redirect failing

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, http, redirect

When I navigate to `http://example.com` it correctly redirects to `https://example.com`.

The problem I'm having is that when I navigate to `http://example.com/sub/directory/page.htm` it redirects to `https://example.comsub/directory/page.htm`.

Why is it not redirecting to `https://example.com/sub/directory/page.htm`?

Here is the apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com

        Redirect permanent / https://example.com/

</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

#NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerName example.com

        [...]

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPass               /          http://localhost:8444/
        ProxyPassReverse        /          http://localhost:8444/

</VirtualHost>
```

The Apache version I am using:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2017-09-18T15:09:02
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration seems correct:

```
Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
```

The [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive should append everything from after the URL-path verbatim to the target. 
A request for `http://example.com/sub/directory/page.htm` should indeed append  `sub/directory/page.htm` to `https://example.com/`  and redirect to `https://example.com/sub/directory/page.htm`

Your remark *"when I navigate to"* seems to indicate that you are testing from a webbrowser.

That has a number of potential issues specific to using modern browsers:

- **Browsers cache permanent redirects** so any changes you make in Apache configuration won't be picked up, your webbrowser will go directly to the cached target URL, without first connecting to your webserver.
- Most sites which support TLS and redirect from http to https also set [**HTTP Strict Transport Security**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) headers. That should also  have the effect that  your browser won't connect to your plain http site and will actively rewrite the plain http URL's you enter to https.
- There may also be multiple (cached) redirects and/or rewrite rules active on not only your HTTP site but also on the HTTPS site

Sometimes testing from a new incognito/anonymous browser window prevents such issues, but mostly I simply test from a command line e.g. `curl -v http://example.com/sub/directory/page.htm`